# AWS full-stack react app. Build failed to complete successfully

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-amplify

I'm trying to make an SPA in React with AWS.

While I was going through the basic steps here ([Step 3 ADD AUTHENTICATION](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-three/?e=gs2020&p=build-a-react-app-two) ) :

I deployed the changes to the live environment, but the build failed.

I'm getting this error.

[image]

Can anyone please explain to me what caused this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue in the Amplify GitHub and can happen when the Amplify CLI version used by the Amplify Console is mismatched with the version you are using locally. Here is some more information: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/6117#issuecomment-794176834

Compare your Amplify App -> Build Settings -> Build image settings -> Amplify CLI version with your version installed on your development machine by running `amplify --version`

Answer (score 0):

Other than checking for version matching, I also have found out if amplify backend doesn't have a role attached to it, the built process is going to fail. to do that you follow the link bellow directions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/how-to-service-role-amplify-console.html
However, before that, go to the General tab under App settings to see if the role is empty or not. You might already have a role, if not follow that link.